# PHP echo a google sign-in button

Tags: php, google-oauth

When I'm using this code from the [official Google dev website](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button), it will render the sign in button as it should:

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
```

But when I'm trying to create this button via PHP, using simple `echo` command, it won't show anything. Anyone knows why and what can I do abut it?

This is the PHP code:

```
$html = '';

$html .= '<span id="signinButton">';
  $html .= '<span';
    $html .= 'class="g-signin"';
    $html .= 'data-callback="signinCallback"';
    $html .= 'data-clientid="XXXXX"';
    $html .= 'data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"';
    $html .= 'data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"';
    $html .= 'data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">';
  $html .= '</span>';
$html .= '</span>';

echo $html;
```

This is the output of the PHP code:

```
<span id="signinButton"><spanclass="g-signin"data-callback="signinCallback"data-clientid="85266228175-pl3302nr5m1ephd64oggies00ec6u224.apps.googleusercontent.com"data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"></span></span>
```

Comment: It should not matter at all whether it was from a static HTML document or generated from a PHP echo. Can you show the HTML output  (view source) of the page generated from PHP? You might actually figure out your mistake when you see the generated HTML.

Comment: Can you show us how you used it in an echo?

Comment: Do you notice that there are no spaces between your attributes? Try adding some...

Comment: Add a space after like this  '<span '

Comment: Change `$html .= '<span';` to `$html .= '<span ';` - or `$html .= 'class="g-signin"';` to `$html .= ' class="g-signin"';`

Comment: @smerny Oh man! This is so silly :) That solved the problem! :) You can suggest that as an answer so I'll be able to vote your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Amitay, that's okay... it's something you'll learn to check if you continue doing web development. I've done as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have issues with something generated by PHP you should always check the HTML that was generated. In this case if you checked the HTML you may have noticed the lack of spaces separating your tagnames and attributes.

You can add spaces to your string where needed. The first couple instances for example...

```
...
$html .= '<span ';
$html .= 'class="g-signin" ';
...
```

You could also consider a different way, like just putting this HTML outside of PHP tags in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = '';

$html .= '<span id="signinButton">';
  $html .= '<span ';
    $html .= 'class="g-signin" ';
    $html .= 'data-callback="signinCallback" ';
    $html .= 'data-clientid="XXXXX" ';
    $html .= 'data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" ';
    $html .= 'data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction" ';
    $html .= 'data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">';
  $html .= '</span>';
$html .= '</span>';

echo $html;
```

it seems like you was forgetting the spaces. The above should work.

Answer (score 1):

You've put everything in a line here. You need to add spaces in every line like this:

```
$html .= ' class="g-signin"';
```

(see between "'" and "class")

Otherwise your ouput would be:

```
<span id="signinButton"><spanclass="g-signin"data-callback="....
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$html .= '<span';` to `$html .= '<span ';`

or `$html .= 'class="g-signin"';` to `$html .= ' class="g-signin"';`

You had a missing space between the words "span" and "class" in `<spanclass`

However, you should add spaces for all of them, since the rest of the codes are bunched up which makes it that much more harder to read in HTML source.

```
$html = '';

$html .= '<span id="signinButton">';
  $html .= '<span ';
    $html .= 'class="g-signin"';
    $html .= ' data-callback="signinCallback"';
    $html .= ' data-clientid="XXXXX"';
    $html .= ' data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"';
    $html .= ' data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"';
    $html .= ' data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">';
  $html .= '</span>';
$html .= '</span>';

echo $html;
```

Comment: Cool fender logo, strato or tele ?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 Thanks. USA Strat actually. Circa '83 custom cherry stain and an oak (veneer) pickguard. Rebuilt it from a basket case. *One of a kind* ;-)

Comment: Very nice, you can deliver your sound to my 48 ch Allen&Heath and do some Decadence dance :D. Will be cool get it screaming on 40MW electro voice rig hahaaaha

Comment: Sounds Sah-weet! @Nucleo1985 She growls on her '68 Super Reverb with a tube screamer ;-) a slight dash of what SRV used; one my guitar heros.

Comment: Dont make it too crispy, i dont want it triggering the compressor lol

Comment: @Nucleo1985 Like satin and velour with a slight *roughened on the edges* ;-)

Comment: Mamma mia belissimo :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804902/best-or-correct-way-for-accessing-json-object?noredirect=1#comment44019029_27804902