# Best or Correct way for accessing json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have json response within following format:

```
[
  {
    "0": [
        {
            "tVote": "32"
        }
    ],
    "1": [
        {
            "choice": "Barcelona",
            "tbAns": "2"
        },
        {
            "choice": "Bayern Muenchen",
            "tbAns": "2"
        },
        {
            "choice": "Juventus",
            "tbAns": "20"
        },
        {
            "choice": "Manchester United",
            "tbAns": "5"
        },
        {
            "choice": "Real Madrid",
            "tbAns": "3"
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "question": "Favorite football team ?"
        }
    ],
    "status": "positive",
    "msg": "Thank you, your vote has been count."
  }
]
```

So far, i accesing it using jQuery ajax within following code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.vote').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parId = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
        var itemId = $(this).prev('input[name=q_id]').val();
        var formAction = $('#' + parId).attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type      : 'POST',
            url       : formAction,
            data      : $('#' + parId + '').serializeArray(),
            dataType  : 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.loadPoll-' + itemId).removeClass('hidden');
            },
            error     : function(request, status, error) {
                $('#' + parId).html('sorry can\'t send your request, please try again later<br>' + status + ' ' + error);
            },
            success   : function(data) {
                $('.loadPoll-' + itemId).addClass('hidden');
                $.each(data, function() {
                    var theQ = data[0][2][0]['question'];
                    var msg = data[0]['msg'];
                    var status = data[0]['status'];
                    var totalVoter = data[0][0][0]['tVote'];
                    var item = data[0][1];
                    var itemLength = data[0][1].length;
                    var itemChoice = data[0][1][0].choice;
                    var parental = $('.vote:focus').closest('form').attr('id');

                    //create html template for response
                    var template = '<div class="clearfix panelPoll">';

                    if(status === 'negative') {
                        $.amaran({
                            content        : {
                                bgcolor: '#FF9900',
                                message: msg,
                                color  : '#fff',
                                icon   : 'fa fa-download'
                            },
                            theme          : 'colorful',
                            position       : 'bottom right',
                            cssanimationIn : 'swing',
                            cssanimationOut: 'bounceOut'
                        });

                        template += '<div class="row bg-info"><p>' + theQ + '</p><code>Total voter: <span class="badge">' + totalVoter + '</code></span></div>';
                        template += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
                        template += '<div class="row resultPollBody">';
                        for(var j = 0; j < itemLength; j++) {
                            //console.log(data[0][1][j].choice); // (debug only)return loop of answer
                            //console.log(data[0][1][j]['tbAns']) // (debug only)return loop of total voter per answer
                            var percent = Math.round((data[0][1][j]['tbAns'] / totalVoter) * 100);
                            (function(j) {

                                template += '<p class="text-primary">' + data[0][1][j].choice + ' <span class="badge">' + data[0][1][j]['tbAns'] + '</span></p>';
                                template += '<div class="progress">';
                                template += '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="' + percent + '" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:' + percent + '%;">' + percent + '%</div>';
                                template += '</div>';
                            })(j)
                        }
                    }
                    else if(status === 'positive') {
                        //code here for new vote
                        $.amaran({
                            content        : {
                                bgcolor: '#008000',
                                message: msg,
                                color  : '#fff',
                                icon   : 'fa fa-download'
                            },
                            theme          : 'colorful',
                            position       : 'bottom right',
                            cssanimationIn : 'swing',
                            cssanimationOut: 'bounceOut'
                        });

                        template += '<div class="row bg-info"><p>' + theQ + '</p><code>Total voter: <span class="badge">' + totalVoter + '</code></span></div>';
                        template += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
                        template += '<div class="row resultPollBody">';
                        for(var j = 0; j < itemLength; j++) {
                            //console.log(data[0][1][j].choice); // (debug only)return loop of answer
                            //console.log(data[0][1][j]['tbAns']) // (debug only)return loop of total voter per answer
                            var percent = Math.round((data[0][1][j]['tbAns'] / totalVoter) * 100);
                            (function(j) {

                                template += '<p class="text-primary">' + data[0][1][j].choice + ' <span class="badge">' + data[0][1][j]['tbAns'] + '</span></p>';
                                template += '<div class="progress">';
                                template += '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="' + percent + '" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:' + percent + '%;">' + percent + '%</div>';
                                template += '</div>';
                            })(j)
                        }
                    }

                    //closing tag for template
                    template += '</div></div>';

                    $('#' + parental).html(function() {
                        $(this).html(template);
                    });
                })
            }
        })
    });
});
```

So, i declaring variable to access the JSON object, for simplicity rather than checking the whole code i cut the var line here:

```
var theQ = data[0][2][0]['question'];
var msg = data[0]['msg'];
var status = data[0]['status'];
var totalVoter = data[0][0][0]['tVote'];
var item = data[0][1];
var itemLength = data[0][1].length;
var itemChoice = data[0][1][0].choice;
var parental = $('.vote:focus').closest('form').attr('id');
```

Its worked and nothing wrong, i got the result i want but i want to know like i stated within title, is this correct way for accessing the JSON or there is correct & simpler way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JSON structure looks a little bit weird but your access is correct. You could try to optimize by caching often used paths like `data[0]` but these are tiny optimizations.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: `$.ajax` parses the response for you and transforms it into an object. Besides, it's pretty obvious the OP is dealing with a javascript object and not a json string.

Comment: Yeah, I automatically answered with one of my 'stock' comments. My bad @MattBurland

Comment: "Its worked and nothing wrong, i got the result i want but i want", ok, so that's certainly one definition of "correct".

Comment: I do see that you do `$.each(data, function() {`. That seems a little bit odd considering you don't use the individual entries or their index. `data[0]` works as long as `data.length` is `1`. That `.each` isn't needed for the JSON you posted.

Comment: @MattBurland despite the 'correct', any better way for accessing it? using `data[0][2][0]['question'];` feels like 'not pro' lol

Comment: @Halcyon Ah ok, i will try changing the `$.each`

Comment: @Nucleo1985: Other than what halcyon said, you don't appear to actually be looping, just accessing the first item and you could just cache at least `data[0]`, you are hobbled by a rather unfortunate json structure using numeric keys for the different sections instead of something more meaningful.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 To make it more readable, you can always "name" the indexes by creating variables. Such as, `var QUESTION = '2'`, and then use that in `data[0][QUESTION][0]['question']`. And as @Halcyon mentioned, you can store `data[0]` into a variable, so you don't have to index into data each time.

Comment: alright, thanks guys for the suggestion. Leave the answer & i will accept it. Once again thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting [a code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi guys, anyone still around? leave me a poke then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is the JSON response part of **YOUR** code?

Because I would definetly spend some time improving that javascript object structure if that is under your control.

For instance, why have the question inside an array inside a `"2"`? And the same for `"0"` and `"1"`.

Why not just having:

```
[
    {
        "question": "Favorite football team ?",
        "tVote": "32",
        "choices": [
            {
                "choice": "Barcelona",
                "tbAns": "2"
            },
            ...
        ],
        "status": "positive",
        "msg": "Thank you, your vote has been count."
    },
    {
        "question": "Another question ?",
        ...
    }
]
```

If you do these changes your javascript code that access this will be a lot more easier to read.

#### Use the $.each properly

You are always using `data[0]`, but I suppose that the reason the first level of the JSON response is an array is because there might be other questions/objects in the response.

If that is true, then you probably want to use each sub-object in the `$.each` instead of `data[0]` always:

```
$.each(function(index, obj) {
    var theQ = obj[2][0]['question']; //notice "obj" instead of "data[0]"
    ...
}
```

#### Use variables instead of copying code

Make variables and use the variables you have in intermediate steps while going deeper in the JSON structure. This will help you improve code readability.

For instance:

```
var item = obj[1]; // according to what I said about $.each
var itemLength = item.length; // instead of obj[1].length
var itemChoice = item[0].choice; // instead of obj[1][0].choice
```

Comment: This is my year old question. Do you still around? if yes give me a poke if you have some time. I have some question. Thanks.